# Mysql: Count(*) fields but display greater value first

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a comment section where parent comments with most likes will show before parent comments with no likes or dislikes, in that order. Similar to how answers are displayed on stackoverflow, where answers with up votes are shown before answers with down votes, though all votes are counted and displayed by the side of the answer. How do I get this done correctly?

I have 2 tables: comment (holds comments), opine (holds likes)
Here's what I have thus far:

```
SELECT comment.*, COUNT(opine.opinion) AS opinion
FROM comment LEFT JOIN
     opine
     ON comment.comment_id = opine.comment_id
WHERE comment.parent = 0
ORDER BY opinion DESC
```

Comment: I assume one of the answers below as miraculously solved your problem, but if not, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an aggregation here:

```
SELECT
    t1.*,
    COALESCE(t2.op_cnt, 0) AS opinion
FROM comment t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT comment_id, COUNT(*) AS op_cnt
    FROM opine
    GROUP BY comment_id
) t2
    ON t1.comment_id = t2.comment_id
WHERE t1.parent = 0   -- or restrict to whichever parents you want
ORDER BY COALESCE(t2.op_cnt, 0) DESC
```

My guess is that you want to count the number of opinions associated with each comment.  If so, then you would want to aggregate by comment and then count.

Comment: This will only give him the "comment_id" field and the count of records from the "opine" table.  He can still select all the fields from "comment", as long as he puts "comment.comment_id" in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Momus No, that's incorrect, and such a query would not even run on certain versions of MySQL.

Comment: Sub-queries are not necessary this case.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT comment.*, op.opinion AS opinion
FROM comment LEFT JOIN
    (select comment_id, count(*) opinion from opine GROUP BY comment_id) op
    ON comment.comment_id = op.comment_id
WHERE comment.parent = 0
ORDER BY opinion DESC
```

Updated based on note

Comment: This query is not valid because you are selecting all comment fields while grouping only by the `id`.

Answer (score -2):

You should be grouping by the comment id to get the correct count of opinions

something along the lines of

```
SELECT comment.*, COUNT(opine.opinion) AS opinion
FROM comment LEFT JOIN
     opine
     ON comment.comment_id = opine.comment_id
WHERE comment.parent = 0
GROUP BY comment.comment_id
ORDER BY opinion DESC
```